# WSO2EMM setup on docker [Publisher not working]

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

Does anyone have a step by step walk through on setting up a production ready WS02 emm enviroment. Preferable on Docker.

I have successfully configured emm, I am able to register a device however I am unable to access https://server-ip:9443/publisher I need publisher to publish apps to the registered device(s).

I do not think the general server setup instructions would be different as I am running from a ubuntu image.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 EMM Enterprise Mobile Management [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mikelasla/wso2emm/)

Dockerfile, 1.1.0, latest

HOW TO USE IT

```
docker run --name wso2emm -p 9443:9443 -p 9763:9763 -d mikelasla/wso2emm
```

Then you can access EMM Admin Console in the following URL

```
https://localhost:9443/emm
```

[WSO2 EMM Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/WSO2+Enterprise+Mobility+Manager)

Just find this using a simple google search. Please give it a try.

Comment: I have tested that image when I got to https://localhost:9443/publisher it doesnt work.  Try it.